# Does the number of unarmed strikes increase with BAB or limbs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, unarmed-combat

When performing an [unarmed strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/strike-unarmed), does a PC get more strikes based on their limbs?

i.e. punching with both hands, knees, headbutt, etc.

Or does the PC get more unarmed strikes based on the BAB?

It states that US is not a natural weapon, but rather considered a light weapon so I'm guessing you get more as your BAB increases but I want to be sure.

I'm curious about this for all the classes, not specifically monk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Both

Unarmed strikes follow the rules for manufactured weapons, despite behaving like natural weapons in a lot of senses (and despite not being manufactured!). That means you get iteratives with them from BAB.

But having more limbs also means you can use two-weapon or multiweapon fighting. These combat styles get more attacks based on the number of limbs. For instance, a four-armed creature with BAB +1, 16 Strength, and Multiweapon Fighting would get four attacks with light or unarmed weapons, for a full-attack of +2/+2/+2/+2. If the creature was a monk and used Flurry of Blows, they’d even get a fifth attack: +0/+0/+0/+0/+0. Note that this is the same whether the creature is using unarmed strikes or, for example, daggers.

Final note: some argue that “unarmed strike” is a single weapon, that you only have one of, and therefore you cannot two-weapon/multiweapon fight with multiple unarmed strikes. That’s stupid and inane, and I’ll have nothing more to say about it beyond mentioning that the argument exists.

Comment: See [Goro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goro_%28Mortal_Kombat%29) ;)

Comment: Ad your final note: Those "some" are usually players of DnD 3ed where indeed unarmed strike was considered a two-handed (all-handed weapon) for the purpose of two- (or multi-) weapon fighting. The idea was that unarmed strike abstracts the whole range of brawl maneuvers, such as punching, kicking, using knees and elbows etc.

In pathfinder it is also possible to use unarmed strike as an off-hand attack if you wield a one handed weapon with no shield and situation calls for it. See GoT fights, especially The Hound, who happily smacks everyone with his armoured fist at every clinch.

Comment: @eimyr I have never heard anyone advancing such an argument make such a case; that's a far more reasonable one than those I have seen. Still, that rule does not exist in 3.5, and specifically removing a rule is pretty good evidence that it wasn't intended to play that way.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right that such a rule does not exists - I played dnd quite some time ago and age taxes the memory. The above was considered a standard rule in all groups I've been a part of. Maybe it's time to ask such a question instead...

Answer (score 1):

Unarmed Strikes basically follow the same rules as fighting with weapons does, though you need to have improved unarmed Strike in order to do lethal damage.

Comment: KRyan is completly correct as far as I can tell, so I won't edit my answer to be more precise